# Create a VM image that's OpenStack compatible

Tags: virtual-machines, openstack

I need to create a image of a CentOS VM which would be OpenStack compatible. I'm having trouble determining on Google what the requirements for OpenStack are. Can someone please help?

My node is on KVM, VM is running CentOS.

Comment: Why don't you just [download one](http://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/)?

Comment: I have an already existent and running CentOS VM with information on it that I need to export in importable to OpenStack format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [guide](http://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/openstack-images.html):

1. Disk partition and filesystem
   While creating the image, you need to have it partitioned and have a filesystem in place occupying the original size of the image. And while booting the image, you need to change the partition table and resize the filesystem as per the flavor specs.
2. MAC address
   Remove any existing MAC address information.
3. SSH server
   Ensure you have SSH server installed and running when the image is booted as it is the primary way to access the instance. You might also need to inject SSH keys as most of the cloud images disable password based SSH login (expect for CirrOS).
4. Disable the firewall
   Disable any firewall rules, since OpenStack has its own set of firewall (called security groups) implemented using iptables.
5. Metadata access from Neutron server
   If your instance requires any user supplied data, it will need to access it via the metadata service.

I think much of the requirements are taken care of by using [cloud-init](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit). The guide even lists tools that can help you with image creation.